# for every integer $n \ge 1$ one has the equality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Could any one help me?

For every integer $n \ge 1$ one has the equality:

$$ 1-{1\over 2}+ {1\over 3}-{1\over 4}+\dots+{1\over 2n-1}-{1\over 2n}={1\over n+1}+{1\over n+2}+\dots +{1\over 2n}.$$

Should I proceed by Induction?

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to do the problem,$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots-\frac{1}{2n}\\=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}-2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\\=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}-\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}$$

If I am not mistaken,this is the Catalan's Identity.

Answer (score 4):

**Sorry, Prism, I didn't see your answer before I posted this.**

Yes, induction works. Check whether it is true for $n=1$. Then, assume that it is true for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Now, observe that when you move from $n$ to $n+1$, all you really need to do is add

$\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$

to the left-hand side and

$-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}$

to the right-hand side. Establish that these two quantities are equal and conclude that the result holds for $n+1$ as well.

Comment: Dear triple_sec, that is okay :) You have explained it more than me, so (+1)!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one way would be by induction. In the inductive hypothesis, you will need to prove
$$\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}$$
which is clearly true.